# What does "this" return in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 questions

1. What does `this` refer to? I understand that it is some kind of container for the object in question.
2. I am trying to pass a variable using a form due to lack of better options. My idea was to have a `<a onclick>` and in the `onclick`, to have `this.form.submit();`

```html
<form action="/justtesting/" method="post">   
     <a onclick="this.form.submit();" href="">click this</a>  
     <input name="pageid" value="12" type="hidden">  
     <input name="mid" value="5" type="hidden">  
</form>
```

And that way I pass the variable.

I have seen this before but instead of `<a>` they used a button.

Comment: add an id to form and use : document.getElementById('idform').submit(), In your case this refers to the current object which is "<a" html anchor

Comment: Two questions should be two separate questions

Comment: Your question is tagged with jquery, but you aren't using jquery

Comment: Two hopefully helpful links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Comment: Thanks everyone using stonia alex's idea with ..       <a onclick="$('#12').submit();"> worked perfectly. so thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:
`this` refers to the object that called the function that is currently executing

The long answer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: juan mendes sorry i will split my question next time, and mrOBrian sorry for including jquery but i guess it would have something to do with it. stoia alex and alexwells thanks for the answer i will check

Answer (score 1):

"this" without any context always refers to the -window- object.

```
var test = 123;

alert(test); // 123
alert(this.test); // 123
```

You'll want to have some sort of jQuery click event for that , searching for whatever value you want to pass along with the form submit.

Comment: In the context of `onclick="this.form.submit"` wouldn't `this` refer to the anchor tag?

Comment: @KevinB, yes it would. And without context it points to the window object when in a browser - not in other environments, where it would point to the global object of that environment.

Comment: Yeah Kevin's right, sorry I should of said that, I was referring to "this" all by itself, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

this refer to the current element , in your case it refers to the `A` tag

if you use  `<Button type="Submit">click this</Button>` then it will work without javascript

And if you use `A` tag then don't leave href attribute as it can cause problem

`<a href="javascript:this.form.submit()">click this</a>`

Answer (score 1):

inside of an in-line binding (e.g. `onclick` or `onload` attribute of an element), `this` refers to the element itself. So, for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="alert(this.href);">Click me</a>
<!-- Alerts "http://google.com" -->

<img src="foo.jpg" width="50" height="50" onload="alert(this.width+'x'+this.height);" />
<!-- Alerts "50x50" -->
```

So by saying `this.form` you're saying "grab the form that this element belongs to (if any)", then you're calling the form element's `submit()` method.

Answer (score 1):

this when passed to an event 
say  refers to the anchor object passed to the function as param.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the case of an event handler, 'this' refers to the target event in question

Example:

```
<div onclick="console.log(this) id="me">click me</div>
```

2. In the case of an object, it refers to the object in question

Example:

```
x = { hi: function(){console.log("Hi "+this.name)}};
x.name= "Bill";
x.hi(); // Hi Bill
```

3 Both these behaviours can be altered by calling a so-called binding, either by using bind, apply or call (bind is implemented here)

```
var bind = function(obj, fn){ return function(){ return fn.apply(obj, arguments)}
y.name = "Joe";
x.hi = bind(y, x.hi);
x.hi(); //Hi Joe
```

4 When no such is specified, this refers to a global object, which equals to window in browsers in compatibility mode, and to undefined in so-called strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

In normal Javascript events, `this` refers to the element which the handler is bound to. However, if your event was bound with `attachEvent` in IE, `this` refers to the window. In your code, `this` refers to the clicked anchor tag. Here's how to properly implement your desired functionality in jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
     $(this).closest("form").submit();
 });
```

Comment: No, it refers to the element the handler is bound to. And not in IE with `attachEvent`, there `this` refers to `window`.